# Error margin for $e$

Tags: calculus

Writing directly from my calculus text:
"We know that $e = \displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n!}$ with an error margin $R_{n} = \displaystyle \dfrac{1}{(n+1)!}$ ..."

How is that deduced?

Comment: From Taylor-Lagrange Formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formulation is a bit confusing. The formula

$$e = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}$$

is exactly correct. No error. Now we can use this formula to get better and better rational approximations to $e$ by cutting off the sum after a finite number, $n$, of terms. (The approximation gets better as $n$ gets higher.)

So for each $n \in \{0, 1, 2, \ldots \} $ we get an approximation of $e$:

$$e \approx \sum_{k = 0}^n \frac{1}{k!} $$

Now this approximation has a margin of error, which is called $R_n$ (the subscript $n$ denotes the dependence on $n$).

What this means is that $R_n$ indicates how far the approximation $\sum_{k = 0}^n \frac{1}{k!}$ lies from the true value of $e$. In formulas this means that the *definition* of $R_n$ lies in the following equality:

$$e = \left(\sum_{k = 0}^n \frac{1}{k!}\right) + R_n$$

Now once you have this equality, it is not hard to see from the first, exact but infinite, expression for $e$ why the book would write:

$$R_n = \frac{1}{(n+1)!} \ldots$$

although I would personally prefer

$$R_n = \frac{1}{(n+1)!} + \ldots$$

or even

$$R_n = \frac{1}{(n+1)!} + \frac{1}{(n+2)!} + \ldots$$

for clarity.

Comment: I understand but how exactly is the $R_{n}$ deduced? What's the algebra behind it?

Comment: Maybe $\text{Margin of error}=e-R_n=..$

Comment: @algevristis: Wait, are you asking about the algebra behind the first expression for $e$, the infinite sum? Or about the algebra of getting from there to $R_n$? I tried to explain the second part in my answer. The first question does not involve $R_n$ in a meaningful way.

Comment: @TymaGaidash, no I am pretty sure it is the other way around: margin of error $= R_n = e - \sum_{k=1}^n 1/k!$

Comment: Approximations have margins of error. E.g. if I approximate $\pi$ by $22/7$ then the margin of error $R$ is $|\pi - 22/7| = 0.00126...$

Comment: So the algebra of computing margin of errors for a given approximation is just 'substract the approximation from the true value'. If I approximate $e$ by $3$ instead of using the approximations from my answer I get a margin of error of $3 - e = 0.2817...$. This approximation is however not good enough for most applications.

Comment: The reason that people 'like' the approximations $\sum_{k=0}^n 1/k!$ so much is that the successive margins of error $R_n$ in this case get smaller and smaller and smaller really quickly as $n$ gets bigger.

Comment: However the important conceptual point is that $e$ itself does not come with a margin of error. Only specific approximations do

Comment: By Taylor's residue theorem $e-\sum^n_{k=1}\frac{1}{k!}=\frac{e^\xi}{(n+1)!}=:R_n$ where $0<\xi<1$. Thus $0<R_n<\frac{e}{(n+1)!}$. For example, if $n=5$, $R_5\approx0.003775391$